# Command 'channel-discovery' is not valid, try 'pear help'

Tags: php, symfony1, pear

while installing symfony1 through windows commend line given me this error

```
c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16>pear channel-discovery pear.php-project.com
 Command 'channel-discovery' is not valid, try 'pear help'
```

if i use

```
pear channel-discover pear.php-project.com
```

then it give me

```
Discovering channel pear.php-project.com over http:// failed with message: chann
el-add: Cannot open "http://pear.php-project.com/channel.xml" (Connection to `pe
 ar.php-project.com:80' failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No
 such host is known. )
Trying to discover channel pear.php-project.com over https:// instead
Discovery of channel "pear.php-project.com" failed (channel-add: Cannot open "ht
tps://pear.php-project.com/channel.xml" (Connection to `pear.php-project.com:443
' failed: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable i
t when you configured PHP?))
then it give me this error
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
pear channel-discover pear.php-project.com
```

Looks like it should be `channel-discover` and not `channel-discovery`

I got it from this url:

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.channels.php

If you want to register the symfony channel, you'll need to use this command:

```
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
```

This link provides the rest of the instructions: http://pear.symfony-project.com/

Comment: thanx for quick answer,i have tried what you said,but i got another error check my question i have edit it.

Comment: What project is this channel for "pear.php-project.com"? I'm not sure if that exists. I could be wrong though.

Comment: i am trying to install symfony through windows commend line using guide of symfony